# cant work, add string to Arraylist when, it's equal to same value in list dont add to Arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist, addition, element, equals

Hello I'm working on a program and I cant work this out, i only have 2 weeks of experience with C#. I think i have to use a Dynamic arraylist. I dont have a size. it keeps growing when i receive strings. For this example, i want to make an arraylist to save data I receive.(can be strings or ints...) 
i got the information from: http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist

Now I want to compare the value with the values thats been saved in the list. But i've no idea, so far i got..

```
        //int numbernr;
        string number = text.Remove(3);
        //int.TryParse(number, out numbernr); //(when/if necessary)
        ArrayList List = new ArrayList();
        if (!List.Contains(number))     //Equals
        {
            List.Add(number);    //list.Insert(1, number);
            MessageBox.Show(number + "added");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("already exist");
        }
```

if number doesnt exist. put number in the list and show it. if the number does exist then say already exist. and i want to get the element of de list. anyone got an idea? cause its not working.

Comment: Better use a generic list. LIST<STRING> or LIST<INT> according to your need.

Comment: A generic isn't going to work when the values can be strings or integers. `List<Object>` is no better than `ArrayList`.

Comment: i think he want's a integer list here ? because he tried to parse the string value to integer in commented code...

Comment: You can create custom type for working with strings and integers at once

Comment: @YuriDorokhov You could, but what benefit would this give? `string` and `int` share virtually nothing in common.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I offered simple solution. It does not give any benefits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare the list outside the method... and use a generic list

```
private List<int> theList = new List<int>();
```

inside the method:

```
string numberString = text.Remove(3); //also are you sure this returns a string?
int number;
if(int.TryParse(numberString, out number))
{
    //ArrayList List = new ArrayList(); you would create a new list over and over so remove this line
    if (!theList.Contains(number))     //Equals
    {
        theList.Add(number);    //list.Insert(1, number);
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} added",number));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("already exist");
    }
}
else MessageBox.Show("invalid number entered");
```

Comment: thank you. i did declae the list on the wrong place. I will get more information about the generic list. and i have a function that i receive a string of 6 characters and i only need the first 3.

Answer (score 0):

The use of a List may be handy here. When recieving a INT, just parse it to string and then use the !List.Contains(value) function to add it.

Result will be something like:

> List myList;
>
> if(myList == null) myList = new List();
>
> string value = "stringValue"; //if string
>
> string value2 = myInteger.ToString(); //if integer
>
> if(!myList.Contains(value OR value2) myList.Add(value OR value2) //depending on the value entered

Hope this will work for you